# Haskell Pipes: How do I sort the output of a producer?

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I have the following piece of code:

```
import Control.Monad (unless)
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import System.FilePath.Posix ((</>))
import System.Posix.Directory (DirStream, openDirStream, readDirStream)

produceFiles :: DirStream -> Producer FilePath IO ()
produceFiles ds = do
  path <- lift $ readDirStream ds
  yield path
  unless (path == "") $ produceFiles ds

getDC :: FilePath -> Producer FilePath IO ()
getDC top = do
  ds <- lift $ openDirStream top
  produceFiles ds

runTest top = runEffect $ getDC top >-> P.map (top</>) >-> P.stdoutLn
```

It prints all the files in the directory `top`. How do I sort the output before I print it? Do I need to write a consumer that "drains" the output first into a list and then sorts it? I'm using pipes-4.1.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toListM` from [`Pipes.Prelude`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.8/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html) converts a producer into a list. We can use that and proceed without `pipes` afterwards:

```
runTest top = do
  ds <- P.toListM (getDC top >-> P.map (top</>))
  mapM_ print $ sort ds
```

Or a bit more pipe-like using usual monadic operators:

```
runTest top = P.toListM (getDC top >-> P.map (top</>)) >>= mapM_ print . sort
```

Grabbing all the `Producer` contents brings us outside streaming abstraction, which is why `toListM` returns a plain list instead of being a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to drain the output first, either into a list our some other structure. Sorting is inherently non-streaming because it may be, for instance, that the last element coming in should be the first going out.